# The integration of a few rows in one row in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to perform the integration of an unspecified number of rows to one row in sql.
I need a sql query to do this.

**My view:**

```
service_id  title   value
----------  -----   -----
1              A    10
1              B    20
1              C    40
2              A    15
2              B    72
2              C    70
.              D     .
.              F     .
.              .     .
```

**Result I expected was:**

```
service_id  A   B   C   D F ..
----------  -   -   -   - - ---
1          10   20  40  . . .
2          15   72  70  . . .
.
.
```

The number of fields is unknown  ( A,B,C , ... )

Comment: Could you post whatever you have tried so far?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: The number of fields is unknown ( A,B,C , ... )

Answer (score 1):

If you want use this in MySQL you can use this

```
select service_id  , group_concat(`titlevalue` separator ',') as `your_fild_name` from ( select id, concat(`title`, ':',  group_concat(`value` separator ',')) as `titlevalue` from your_table_name group by id, `titlevalue`) tbl group by service_id  ;
```